# Toggle nav based on screen resize

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am building a site using Bootstrap 3, particularly the navigation collapse feature. I have it working so that on small screens the main nav is collapsed and then displays on larger screens.

The issue I have is the header is fixed on large screen and I have been asked to make the main nav collapsed by default, and appear when the user either hovers or clicks (for larger handhelds) anywhere in the header. I have achieved some of this by checking the window size and hiding the nav accordingly.

What I am having trouble with is when the window is resized it can make the nav open and close multiple times. Plus I don't want this script to work on small screens as that uses Bootstraps collapse feature.

Here is what I have.

HTML:

```
<header class="navbar-fixed-top" id="header">
    <div class="top">
        <div class="logo">
            Logo here
        </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="main-navbar">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav nav-justified">
                    <li class=""><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
</header>
```

JS:

```
var $window = $(window);

function checkWidth() {
    var windowsize = $window.width();

    if (windowsize >= 768) {
        $('#main-navbar').hide();
        $('#header').hover( function() {
            $('#main-navbar').slideToggle();
        } );
    } else {
        $('#main-navbar').show();
    }
};

// Check the width on load.
checkWidth();

// Bind event listener everytime the window size changes.
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CreativeDSG/4097x2av/).

How would I get the script to stop running multiple times and to reset each time the screen size is adjusted?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `$('#main-navbar').slideToggle();`

Use `$('#main-navbar').slideDown();`

`$('#main-navbar').slideToggle();` will trigger non stop.

Also consider: `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()` to listen for hovers and when the mouse leaves the hover target.

======

```
if (windowsize >= 768) {
    $('#main-navbar').hide();
    $('#header').hover( function() {
        $('#main-navbar').slideToggle();
    } );
} else {
    $('#main-navbar-collapse').hide();
    $('.navbar-toggle').on('click', function(){
        $('#main-navbar-collapse').toggle();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It solves some of my issues, the multiple opening. However the other part I need to do is to display the #main-navbar on smaller devices (less than 768) and remove the mouse enter feature. My script does not seem to be doing anything for small screens once I resize.